# Does closing of input/output stream gotten from getInput/OutputStream() affects recreation of underlying Socket?

Tags: java, android, http, networking

I've already looked through resources which describe specifics of work with `HttpURLConnection` as in Java so in Android (where there is not default implementation of working with connection pool) and my question is: if I close a stream gotten from `HttpURLConnection`, will the system create a new one `Socket` at a next time when I establish a `HttpURLConnection` with the same `URL` or it will try to use an exist one? Considering the following code:

```
private byte[] downloadText(URL url, String data) {
   OutputStream out = null;
   InputStream in = null;
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   try {
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setReadTimeout(20 * 1000);
      conn.setConnectTimeout(15 * 000);
      conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

      byte[] payload = data.getBytes("utf-8");
      conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(payload.length);

      conn.connect();

      out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
      out.write(payload);
      out.flush();

      final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
      final String responseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

      is = conn.getInputStream();

      if((responseCode / 100) == 2 || responseMessage.equals("OK")) {
         return readFromStream(is);
      }
   } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred while trying to connect to the server" + e.toString());
   } finally {
      try {
         if(out != null) {
             out.close();
         }

         if(is != null) {
            is.close();
         }
      } catch(IOException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred while trying to close data streams" + e.toString());
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. If there isn't a connection pool, there is no 'existing socket' to reuse.

Comment: Do you mean that I should create a connection pool by myself?